# How to check if a list is not contains a value in Thymeleaf?

Tags: list, thymeleaf

I can check if a list contains a value, like;

`${#lists.contains(data, '1')}`

But, how can I check if a list is **not** contains a value ?

Comment: Have you tried `${!#lists.contains(data, '1')}` ?

Comment: @wimDeblauwe yes, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invert the condition by using `!`.

Suppose you have this in your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("data", List.of(1));
```

Then you can do:

```
<div th:if="${#lists.contains(data, 1)}">1 is present</div>
<div th:if="${!#lists.contains(data, 2)}">2 is not present</div>
```

This will output:

> 1 is present
>
> 2 is not present

Note that I did not quote the number, otherwise, it is a String.

Comment: There is another subtle issue here, also: `String` vs `char`: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958688/handling-integers-as-strings-in-thymeleaf-arrays-and-lists). This is relevant if you are using Thymeleaf (with OGNL), but not Spring (SpEL), where you have a **single-character string literal** such as the example of `'1'` used in this question.