# Handling Integers as Strings in Thymeleaf Arrays and Lists

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Why do the following Thymeleaf `th:if` tests fail for the strings "0", "1", and "9"?

I have a Java array as follows:

```
String[] arrayData = {"x", "-1", "0", "1", "9", "10", "11"};
```

The `"x"` is included to clarify that this array can contain alphabetic values as well as numeric values.

I have a Thymeleaf template containing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <div th:if="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, '-1')}"
             th:text="'found array string \'-1\''"></div>
                
        <div th:if="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, '0')}"
             th:text="'found array string \'0\''"></div>
                
        <div th:if="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, '1')}"
             th:text="'found array string \'1\''"></div>
                
        <div th:if="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, '9')}"
             th:text="'found array string \'9\''"></div>
        
        <div th:if="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, '10')}"
             th:text="'found array string \'10\''"></div>
        
        <div th:if="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, '11')}"
             th:text="'found array string \'11\''"></div>
                
    </body>

</html>
```

I expect this to generate the following output in a browser:

```
found array string '-1'
found array string '0'
found array string '1'
found array string '9'
found array string '10'
found array string '11'
```

But I actually get the following:

```
found array string '-1'
found array string '10'
found array string '11'
```

**Question**: Why do the tests fail for the strings `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"9"`? What am I doing wrong?

All such tests for the ten string values "0" through "9" fail. Anything outside that range works as expected.

The same thing happens if I use an `ArrayList<String>`, with the Thymeleaf `#lists.contains()` operator.

The Thymeleaf version is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As far as I can tell, I think the Thymeleaf code which implements the `#arrays.contains()` function is [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3a8366126d51461e59bfdc5676fea334b1184a72/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/util/ArrayUtils.java#L82) - and it looks straightforward.

My Java version is AdoptOpenJDK 14.

I am **not** using Spring in this specific scenario.

---

**Update, After Answer was Provided**

If I test with any single character (e.g. `x`) the same problem happens as with `0` through `9`. So the title is somewhat misleading in that regard.

Comment: That's extremely odd. Please include the code where you're building the Thymeleaf context and invoking the engine.

Comment: When I run a (very) similar test locally, everything appears correctly: `found array string -1, found array string 0, found array string 1, found array string 9, found array string 10, found array string 11`.  Using spring `5.2.9.RELEASE` and thymeleaf `3.0.11.RELEASE`.

Comment: @Metroids - interesting - thank you. I am not using Spring at all in my scenario. I will try a Spring version, when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that if you aren't using `Spring`, Thymeleaf expressions are being interpreted using `OGNL` insteald of `SPeL` -- which appears to treat single character constants as type `char` instead of type `String` and so the `#arrays.contains` expressions fail to match.

I don't have a setup to test OGNL, but according to [this post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Problem-with-thymeleaf-expression-utility-lists-contains-td4027317.html), this should work:

```
<div th:text="${#arrays.contains(arrayData, &quot;0&quot;)}" />
```

(Or maybe `#arrays.contains(arrayData, '' + '0')` would work?)

Comment: Thank you - the link in your answer explains my problem. If I had tested with `x` I would have seen the same problem as testing with `0` through `9`. Your `'' + '0'` suggestion works, to force a cast from `char` to `String`.